# Clone Record with lightning web component

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, clone, duplicate-value

I want to clone the template, and I want its name to be a concatination between the name of the template that I cloned with the id of the sales that I selected, as a result I want to have a template that like name: "idSalesSelected-NameOfTheTemplateCloned" .

The problem I have now is that I get  the templateName as :  undifened-undefined and how I can interpret this processing in clone button ?

==> Apex Class :

```
  @AuraEnabled (cacheable=true)

  public static List<String> getSales(){
  List<Sales__c> orgs = [SELECT  Name  FROM Sales__c ];
  List<String> names = new List<String>();
        for(Sales__c org : orgs){
            names.add(org.Name);
        }
        return names;
      }

      @AuraEnabled (cacheable=true)

      public static Template__c getFormTemplateName(){

        Template__c  template = [SELECT name FROM Template__c LIMIT 1];

        Template__c  eCopy = template .clone( false, false, false, false );

        return eCopy;
      }


      @AuraEnabled (cacheable=true)

      public static Sales__c  getSalesId(){

        Sales__c  salesName = [SELECT  SAP_Sales__c FROM Sales__c LIMIT 1];

        return salesName;
      }


     
}
```

==> JS

```
 lstSelected = [];
    @track lstOptions = [];
    @track sales = [];
    @track sales2 = [];
    @track objectFields = [];
    @track templateName;
  
    @wire(getSales)
    getSales({ error, data }) {
        console.log('teste méthode ');
        console.log('teste data '+data);
        if (data) {
            let option = [];
            for (let key in data) {
                option.push({ label: data[key], value: key });
            }
            this.sales = option;
            this.sales2 = option;
        } else if (error) {
            console.log('error' + error);
        }
    }

    closeQuickAction() {
        this.dispatchEvent(new CloseActionScreenEvent());
    }
 
// New US
   
@wire(getFormTemplateName) formTem;
      
get Name() {
    return this.formTem.data  ? getSObjectValue(this.formTem.data, NAME_FIELD) : '';
    
}

@wire(getSalesId) salesOrg;
      
get SAP_Sales__c() {
    return this.salesOrg.data  ? getSObjectValue(this.salesOrg.data, SAP_Sales_FIELD) : '';
    
}

get templateName() {
    return `${this.SAP_Sales_FIELD} ${this.Name_FIELD}`;
}

connectedCallback(){
    console.log('*******************************');
    this.templateName = this.SAP_Sales_FIELD + "-" + this.Name_FIELD;
    console.log(this.templateName);

    
}
```

==> HTML

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="  Duplicate Form ">
            <lightning-dual-listbox name="getSales"
                                    values={sales} 
                                    options={sales}
                                    ></lightning-dual-listbox>
<br><br><br>
               
            <div class="slds-modal__footer">
                <button class="slds-button slds-button_neutral" aria-label="Cancel and close"  type="Cancel" onclick={closeQuickAction}>Cancel</button>
                <button class="slds-button slds-button_brand">Clone</button>
              </div>
           


             

    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

This is what I added :

```
handleOnChange(event){
    this.selectedId = event.detail.value;
}

clone(){
    getFormTemplateName({TemplateId : this.recordId})
    .then(data => {
        console.log('data is '+data)

        this.nameTem = data.Name;
        console.log('nom est'+this.nameTem);
    }).catch(err =>  
            console.log('une erreur existe 1'+JSON.stringify(err)))  

    getSalesId({TemplateId : this.recordId})
            .then(data => {
 
this.sapid = data.SAP_Sales__c ;
console.log('sap est '+this.sapid);
}).catch(err => 
            
    console.log('une erreur existe 2'+JSON.stringify(err)))  

this.templateName = this.sapid+ "-"+ this.nameTem ;
console.log('template name is '+this.templateName);

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. If you check the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm#apex_System_SObject_clone) of the sObject clone() method, you can see that if you wish to create a completely separate clone (deep copy) that does not reference the original object's field, you have to pass the second parameter as true, if not, you are just creating a shallow copy of the original object and when modifying a field, it will affect the original.
2. On your dual list box, you have to implement a method associated with the onchange event, like this:

   ```
   <lightning-dual-listbox name="getSales"
                                values={sales} 
                                options={sales}
                                onchange={handleOnChange}
                                ></lightning-dual-listbox>
   ```

Then on the js something like this:

```
handleOnChange(event){
      this.selectedId = event.detail.value;
}
```

If you wish to make a separate clone of the original object and assign a different name to it, you just have to do

```
@AuraEnabled (cacheable=true)
public static Template__c getFormTemplateName(String salesId){

    Template__c  template = [SELECT name FROM Template__c LIMIT 1];

    Template__c  eCopy = template .clone( false, true, false, false );
    eCopy.Form_TemplateID__c = salesId + template.Name;

    return eCopy;
}
```

Then, link your clone button to a method that calls the getFormTemplateName and pass the sales id as parameter, something like:

```
clone(){
     getFormTemplateName({salesId: this.selectedId})
     .then(result => console.log(result)).catch(err => console.log(err))
}
```

You wish in this case to call imperatively the apex method, instead of wiring it, because you wish to select the id first to then call the method.

Just an advice: name better your methods and variables. "getFormTemplateName" doesn't indicate a cloning process, it just suggests that you are fetching a name of a template and nothing else. Something like "cloneTemplate" or "getCopiedFormTemplate" is more adecuate for your scenario.

Comment: thank you for your help , but I have a question , in my situation I need to concatenate the Id that I get from another object `Sales__c ` with the name of template and also is from another object , the name is the same of the what I want to clone , but the ID (field ) is the ID of the sales that I will selected in my listbox

Comment: @SalesforceJuniorDev I'm sorry, I don't understand very well your question. The Id field of an sObject is autogenerated when you insert it to the database. You can only set another Id of another record of the same sObject type (in this case, Template__c), and if that is the case, you would be modifying the original record when doing a update operation on it. Maybe you mean that you have a custom "SalesId__c" lookup field, where you can assign the Sales id that you selected.

Comment: yes exactly , I have a custom field that is an ID , this field is `SAP_Sales__c` that I select in my apex method `getSalesId ` , and what I want is to concatenate the `Name `FROM  `Template__c ` that it will be cloned , with the `SAP_Sales__c` FROM `Sales__c`

Comment: @SalesforceJuniorDev The code I provided "eCopy.Name = salesId + template.Name;" is what you are saying, concatenating the SAP_Sales__c value that you selected on your lwc action with the name of the original Template__c record. I don't understand why this is not meeting your requirement. Please, be more specific. Do you need to assign that concatenation to another field on the eCopy object?

Comment: @SalesforceJuniorDev that SAP_Sales__c value is being sent to the action with your getSalesId method. When you select it on the action, you click on the clone button and the clone() method on the js is calling the apex method and passing the value

Comment: what I mean is that the SAP_Sales__c and the Name are in deferent object ,  that yes , I want to get the concatenation value in another field on the eCopy object  named Form_TemplateID__c

Comment: @SalesforceJuniorDev it's not importante if the SAP_Sales__c value and Name values are in different objects, the code I provided is considering that (using the name from the template record (the one obtained in the query) and the salesId that is obtained from the parameter. If you wish to concatenate both of those values to Form_TemplateID__c, then you just have to replace "eCopy.Name =" to "eCopy.Form_TemplateID__c =".